# Scipy optimization of function with several variables

Tags: python, scipy

I have a function with 2 variables and I try to minimize it using L-BFGS-B method.

```
def f(x,y):
    z = exp(x + y)
return z
```

My arguments are numpy arrays, x0 is (0,0). I try something like:

```
res = minimize(f,x0,args=(x,y), method = "L-BFGS-B")
```

and get the error saying I give 3 arguments instead of 2. What is going wrong?

Comment: Does dropping `args=(x, y)` help?

Comment: Nope. And I don't need to drop them since I minimize function on a bounded space

Comment: @Mephy sorry, forgot to mention you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `args` parameter is for passing in extra data to your objective function. In your case, the objective function should take one argument: the point at which it should be evaluated as an array. For instance:

```
def f(x):
    return np.exp(x.sum())

minimize(f, [0,0], bounds=[[-5,None], [-5,None]])
```

I imagine that you're optimizing a function other than the exponential, right? Because minimizing it is obviously trivial...